# RESTFul web service from html on IOS

Tags: ios, html, rest, post, ios-simulator

Following is the technologies that I have used:
HTML 5, JS, JQuery, AJAX, RESTFul POST web service, IOS

Problem Statement:

I have created an iOS native application and placed certain HTML and JS files in my application. On starting the application on simulator I open my HTML file in web view and on click of a button I hit a web service that is deployed on my local windows machine.

However, I am not able to hit my web service. I am able to perform the same activity from Android emulator and from my local client test program.

Request you to please help me with this issue.

Below is the AJAX code that hits the service:

```
var jsonObject  = new Object();
jsonObject.passengers= 4;
jsonObject.country= "India";
jsonObject.state= "Maharashtra";

var url = "http://<HOST>:<POST>/JerseyTest/services/emanual/demo";
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: inputJsonString,
    success: function(data, status){
            alert("success");
            alert("In Success: " + JSON.stringify(status));
            alert("In Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            //$("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
    },
    error:function(data, status){
            alert("failure");
            alert("In Error: " + JSON.stringify(status));
            alert("In Error: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            //$("#result").html('There is error while submit');
    }
    });
```

This code works on from standalone HTML file, from Android Emulator.
Is there any extra configuration that I need to do on iOS machine or for simulator?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jQuery is loaded by putting an `alert("jQuery is loaded")` inside

```
$(function(){
    alert("jQuery is loaded")
});
```

If jQuery isn't loaded, check in XCode if the jQuery source file is inside the Compile Sources which is under the Build Phases tab in the project Target. If it is, remove it and add it to Copy Bundle Resources.

Also, try formatting the AJAX like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function(xhr, status, error){
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    },
    data: {key: "value"},
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Error");
        console.log("Error");
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CORS issue. Make sure your REST service headers include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```